# TinyMCE formatting feature stops working in modal dialog

Tags: jquery, tinymce, simplemodal

I got a weird bug when using TinyMCE (4.0.16) inside a modal dialog. The first time I use the dialog it works fine. TinyMCE initializes correctly and formatting features (bold, underline, etc) works just fine.

Then I click on OK (or whatever button that closes the dialog). If I go back in the modal dialog, TinyMCE editors are still present, but not the formatting features won't work anymore.

jQuery: 1.4.4 (I know it's old but that's what I need to use)
dialog plugin: [jQuery SimpleModal 1.4.4](http://www.ericmmartin.com/simplemodal-1-4-4-released/)

Here is the code used when opening the modal dialog:

```
$("#add-new-custom-notice-modal").modal({
minWidth: 800,
maxWidth: 950,
maxHeight: 575,
onShow: function (dialog) {

    var objTinyMceEditorFrench = tinymce.get("strNewCustomDescriptionFr");

    if (objTinyMceEditorFrench) {
        objTinyMceEditorFrench.setContent(strCustomDescriptionContentFr);
    } else {

        tinymce.init({
            selector: "#strNewCustomDescriptionFr",
            theme: "modern",
            menubar: false,
            plugins: ["paste"],
            theme_advanced_path : false,
            statusbar : false,
            paste_as_text: true,
            language: gstrLocale
        });

        var objNewTinyMceEditorFrench = tinymce.get("strNewCustomDescriptionFr");
        objNewTinyMceEditorFrench.setContent(strCustomDescriptionContentFr);
    }

    var objTinyMceEditorEnglish = tinymce.get("strNewCustomDescriptionEn");

    if (objTinyMceEditorEnglish) {
        objTinyMceEditorEnglish.setContent(strCustomDescriptionContentEn);
    } else {

        tinymce.init({
            selector: "#strNewCustomDescriptionEn",
            theme: "modern",
            menubar: false,
            plugins: ["paste"],
            theme_advanced_path : false,
            statusbar : false,
            paste_as_text: true,
            language: gstrLocale
        });

        var objNewTinyMceEditorEnglish = tinymce.get("strNewCustomDescriptionEn");
        objNewTinyMceEditorEnglish.setContent(strCustomDescriptionContentEn);
    }               
},

onClose: function (dialog) {

    var objTinyMceEditorFrench = tinymce.get("strNewCustomDescriptionFr");

    if (objTinyMceEditorFrench) {
        objTinyMceEditorFrench.remove();    
    }

    var objTinyMceEditorEnglish = tinymce.get("strNewCustomDescriptionEn");

    if (objTinyMceEditorEnglish) {
        objTinyMceEditorEnglish.remove();                   
    }

    $.modal.close();
}
});
```

Any idea?

Many thanks for help

Charles

Comment: This is one of those questions that we might need a jsffidle to help

Comment: Never used jsfiddle but I will figure out. Just a few minutes. Thanks!

Comment: better use a tinymce fiddle for this